# Log4J Duplicate Lines in Script Environment - When Don't Control RootLogger

Tags: java, logging, groovy, log4j

Problem: Various log files we've defined as appenders are flooding with duplicate log lines since we turned it on.

I've read many posts about the duplicates problem and the various ways to fix it. I don't believe any of them apply, and feel this is a unique situation.  Here are the distinguishing factors:

1. The environment is a 3rd party JVM which permits groovy code to be executed.
2. We are not at liberty to change the rootlogger properties, or the base log4j configuration.
3. We have to do all the configuration of log4j programmatically.

Given those restrictions and requirements, is it possible to achieve the following: 
1. Don't dump our log lines in the main application log
2. Avoid the duplicate log line issue

Note: I do create my own classloader to execute code, i'm not sure if that is relevant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was due to a mistake on my part in the code, and a misunderstanding of the documentation.  I thought that the additivity had to be set on the rootlogger, but it looks like it can be set on any logger, and it affects propagation toward the rootlogger.

This simple command gave me the desired effect. 
log.setAdditivity(false)

My other problem which made me think this was not working was that loggerName in the following line was not unique due to a parsing issue, and thus many of my classes were getting handles to the same loggers, and giving the appearance of addititvity:

log=getLogger(loggerName)